# d3: difference between sort and ascending

Tags: d3.js

I wanted to know the difference between sort function and ascending function in d3. 
I am looking for a way to rearrange the data in my table in ascending order of the column selected.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Array.sort()` will sort the values alphabetically in ascending order.  `Array.sort(d3.ascending)` will sort the values naturally in ascending order. The difference can be seen when you are sorting a list of numbers.

```
var a = [3,26,1,7];

console.log(a.sort());
// prints [1,26,3,7]

console.log(a.sort(d3.ascending));
// prints [1,3,7,26]
```

For additional information on how `sort` works, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort.

Comment: Then why is this example able to sort numbers using just sort()?
http://bl.ocks.org/3719724

Comment: It doesn't. He passes in a custom comparator to `sort`: `tr.sort(function(a, b) { return (b[k] / b.Total) - (a[k] / a.Total); })`.  The anonymous function(a,b) is the custom comparator that actually does the comparison.  d3.ascending is just shorthand for `function(a, b) {
  return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0;
}`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Also, can you explain why this part is needed in the example? 

`var ages = d3.keys(states[0]).filter(function(key) {
    return key != "State" && key != "Total";
  });`

Comment: Parsing the csv produces an array of values like [{State=..., Total=..., 'Under 5 Years': ..., '5 to 13 Years':...}...] but he only wants the age buckets. So he grabs the keys (`d3.keys`) for the first datum (`states[0]`) and then filters the keys (`filter`) to remove the State and Total columns. This leaves `ages` to equal the column headings for just the different age buckets.

Comment: I see. I am trying to do a similar thing here, separating out the names from the tables and sorting the rest of the parameters (all of which are numerical). But for some reason the sorting does not seem to happen, i see some rows switching but it is not in any order.

Also, I am using generating my table by calling a function and using this code after that call in doc.ready

`var ages = d3.keys(csv[0]).filter(function(key) {
    return key != "names";
});

var tr = d3.selectAll("tbody tr");

d3.selectAll("thead th").data(ages).on("click", function(k) {
 tr.sort(d3.ascending);
});`

Comment: Post all of the d3 code you have in a new question and we can try and figure out what's going on.